# drools-showcase and kie-server-showcase integration

Tags: integration, drools, kie-server

Drools Workbench does not authenticate when calling Kie-Server REST

I'm runnig jboss/drools-workbench-showcase and jboss/kie-server-showcase. Everything ok, kie-server registering itself and I see it in  "Execution servers" and can deploy and run projects. But when I'm trying to view process instances it says "Invalid credentials to load data from remote server. Contact your system administrator". After some investigations I found that WB opens keep-alive connection, sends GET with Authorization header, but the second POST without.

STR

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 --name drools-workbench jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest
docker run -p 8180:8080 -ti --name kie-server --link drools-workbench:kie_wb jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
```

Login with admin:admin and go to the "Process Instances"

HTTP Stream dump

https://pastebin.com/raw/XB2MKUAv

Comment: Having the same issue and try what ever I thought but did not work

Answer (score 0):

use the ./add-user.sh script to add the user to the KIE Server.

As the Drools workbench and Kie server are running in separate JVMs (Containers), they don't share the same jaas subject and security domain. See:
[Unable to view Process Definitions or Process Instances in Business-Central/Decision Central](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4859751)

to quote:

> The Business-Central and kie-server use java jaas login module to authenticate/authorize users. If they stay on one single instance (the same jvm) the same jaas subject and security domain are shared. Therefore, a user authenticated by Business-Central can also access kie-server.
>
> If Business-Central and kie-server are separated in different jvms, the jaas login module will have to be triggered on both. A user who has been authenticated on the Business-Central needs to be authenticated again when accessing kie-server. If the user is not available on kie-server the following error will be thrown in the Business-Central log file: